# Наклонение

Tags: морфология

"Прижать" - какого наклонения?

Comment: А Вы, вообще, что-то слышали о знаках препинания?

Answer (score 1):

Неопределённого (инфинитив).

> ИНФИНИТИВ а, м. В грамматике: то же, что **неопределенное наклонение** глагола.

(Толковый словарь русского языка (Ожегов С., Шведова Н.)

http://slovoblog.ru/?search=%C8%CD%D4%C8%CD%C8%D2%C8%C2

> Отличие **неопределенного наклонения** от личного глагола (verbum finitum) состоит в том, что этот последний заключает в себе определение своего лица (1-го, 2-го или 3-го), тогда как в неопределенном наклонении, вырванном из связи, лицо остается неопределенным.

В. В. Виноградов, "Русский язык".

2001-2012. Учреждение Российской академии наук Институт русского языка им. В. В. Виноградова.

[Состав глагольного слова и его границы](http://slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=5310&0a0=15).

Answer (score 1):

Неопределенного наклонения не существует: их всего три (изъявительное, условное, повелительное). Инфинитив - это неопределенная форма глагола. Прижать - это инфинитив.

Answer (score 0):

Однозначно - инфинитив. Или пример дан не полностью.